# Does each function and ISR get allocated its own stack size

Tags: c++, c, function, portaudio, isr

I'd assume this question is Operating System or platform dependant.

It came about as I was writing C++ code on Windows using the port audio libraries.

It stated in the documentation not to write too much code in my callback function that will be passed to the port audio engine, because depending on the system, it could be called from an ISR and from reading on another forum, stating that it can cause a stack overflow.

I'm not here to ask about anything port audio specific, but I was wondering why would there be an issue with stack space if more code is wrote in an ISR than in the main function.

I wish to call a few different functions from the callback. If this callback is actually called from an ISR, is calling more functions from the ISR a problem?

As I call each function, will this allow me extra stack space because each function has its own maximum stack size? This I find a bit confusing.

I always thought that functions and ISRs can use as much stack stack space as they like up to the complete allocated stack. Does it mean the main function has a larger portion of the stack than others.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd venture a guess and say that the problem might be that you could get a lot of ISRs before each individual callback ends, meaning you'd be allocating stack space for all of them which could cause a stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

> If this callback is actually called from an ISR, is calling more functions from the ISR a problem?

It could be.  There are many flavors of ISR, used in many contexts, and some combinations afford fairly limited stack space to the ISR.  Stack space is used by (at least) the ISR's own parameters and local variables and those of every function it calls, directly or indirectly, with some overhead for function calls.  That space gets reused for sequential function calls, but it is cumulative when one function calls another.

> As I call each function, will this allow me extra stack space because each function has its own maximum stack size?

No, generally not.  An ISR will quite possibly be called with its own stack space, separate from that of any program with which it is associated, but that's a special case.  Functions ordinarily use the same stack as their callers, but ISRs do not *have* callers in the conventional sense.

> I always thought that functions and ISRs can use as much stack stack space as they like up to the complete allocated stack. Does it mean the main function has a larger portion of the stack than others[?]

An ISR can use as much as it likes *of the stack space provided to it*.  That space often is separate from the associated program's main stack, which can be useful for avoiding interfering with the main program's state when the ISR is triggered, and is essential when the ISR is asynchronous.  When separate, the ISR's stack is often much smaller.

The size of a process's (main) stack depends on the system and sometimes the executable; it is shared among `main` and all the functions called directly or indirectly from `main`.  In single-threaded programs, `main` *does* have access to more stack than any other function `f`, but the primary reason for that is `main` and (generally) every function in the call chain from `main` to `f` occupies stack space that `f` cannot use.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering why would there be an issue with stack space if more code is wrote in an ISR than in the main function.

Stack space is probably not the primary concern for an ISR. An ISR should be as simple and fast as possible in order to minimise latency, so it shouldn't *need* a large stack anyway.  If you have to do any non-trivial processing, your ISR should enqueue a task to run on a regular thread later to complete the job (sometimes called top-half and bottom-half). This could be achieved with a condition variable, semaphore, or message queue (to name a few IPC mechanisms). So if an ISR is using a lot of stack, it may be an indication that it's trying to do too much processing during a timing-critical scheduling period.

Also, many systems (e.g. RTOS) require you to declare the stack size for threads and ISRs.

> I wish to call a few different functions from the callback. If this callback is actually called from an ISR, is calling more functions from the ISR a problem?

Only in so far as calling other functions from an ISR should be minimised as discussed above. You *can* call other functions, but you *should* defer as much as possible to run *after* the ISR has returned to the kernel scheduler (and unmasked interrupts!).

Also - beware of race conditions! Careful use of mutexes is necessary to protect shared state.

> As I call each function, will this allow me extra stack space because each function has its own maximum stack size? This I find a bit confusing.

No - a function doesn't have its own stack size - threads do.  For ISRs, it depends on the OS.  Calling each function will *consume* more stack space though (based on the call nesting level).

> I always thought that functions and ISRs can use as much stack stack space as they like up to the complete allocated stack.

Yes, but the stack is per-thread, not per-process like the heap. Using a large amount of stack space could be a sign of a design issue: allocating large objects on the stack rather than the heap, too many nested function calls, etc.

> Does it mean the main function has a larger portion of the stack than others.

No, since the stack is per *thread*. A `main` function will be at the bottom of the application's call stack, but it may consume a small or a large amount of stack, depending only on its local variables.

Some good reading:

- [Call Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Comment: Thanks for that. In the case of a micro controller with just one thread and no OS, what determines the stack size for each ISR ?

Comment: Simply put - the available RAM, minus the program text (static data) and data (application binary) segments, and the heap. It does depend on the language and compiler, but usually the heap grows up from the bottom and the stack grows down. This article has a good diagram: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-logical-explanation-for-stacks-typically-growing-downward-and-heaps-growing-upward

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I wouldn't trust "another forum".

The documentation says nothing about using too much *stack space*. It talks about too much *code*, and in context of an ISR callbacks it means spending too much *time* in the ISR.

The ISR (including callbacks) executes with interrupts blocked. Now interrupts do not accumulate; a controller may only say if the interrupt is pending. If the ISR takes too long to execute, interrupts raised during its execution are lost.

Stack space might be an issue as well, but first and foremost, make your callback fast.

Comment: Thanks. Does the ISR always execute with interrupts blocked though?

Answer (score 0):

> It came about as I was writing C++ code on Windows using the port audio libraries.

Please do as little as possible in the ISR and queue a DPC to call all of your functions.  Even DPCs are or should be resource constrained so consider a design where a worker thread services the DPC.  Whatever you do, don't even think about acquiring any mutexes in an ISR.  EOR.